# how to fetch value from nodes of json code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

hello i am entry level iOS developer and i want to fetch all payLoad value from this Json code.

Json code is

```
:(
    {
    request =         {
        fromId = sam;
        payLoad = helllooooffffff;
        timeZone = IST;
        toId = john;
    };
},
    {
    request =         {
        fromId = sam;
        payLoad = yes;
        timeZone = IST;
        toId = john;
    };
},
    {
    request =         {
        fromId = sam;
        payLoad = Yesssss;
        timeZone = IST;
        toId = john;
    };
},)
```

somebody help me
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to make some sort of attempt to solve your problem yourself before asking on here. And please don't revert the change again you need to format your question correctly not give us rubbish

Comment: i have been working in this problem from yesterday so now i am so tired so post my solve Popeye

Comment: Well if you have been looking at this from yesterday that must mean you have tried something so please share what you have tried. We will not do your work for you, we're here to help solve problems not do you work. You've been told this on other questions you have asked so maybe you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i want to get value payLoad from json code. can you help me?

Comment: Not sure how many times I have to say this. PLEASE SHARE WHAT YOU HAVE ALREADY DONE. So share code of what you have tried, WE WILL NOT DO YOUR WORK FOR YOU.

Comment: You have an array containing 3 dictionaries.  Each of those dictionaries contains another dictionary.  It's very simple if you just consider it a layer at a time.  Peel the onion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have retrieved your JSON into retrieved JSON, you can go through dictionaries like so:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *nmd in retrievedJSON) {
    NSMutableDictionary *request = [nmd objectForKey:@"request"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [request objectForKey:@"payLoad"]);    
}
```

In this particular example, I am going through all dictionaries and NSLogging payLoad. You can assign this value to variable, object and so on.

You can access other keys by using similar syntax.

Comment: @Bhavdip you should mark this answer correct so anyone seeing this post in the future will know that this is the solution